# Delta-wye transformer phase shift

Tags: transformer

For a delta-wye transformer, the primary voltage is in phase with the secondary phase voltage.

Assuming it is an ABC (positive) sequence system with counter clock wise rotation and that phase A to the neutral voltage on the secondary is at 0 degrees.
Then voltage between phase A and B on the primary would be in phase with the phase to neutral voltage on the secondary.
Since, for a wye connection the line to line voltage leads the phase voltage, this means that for a delta-wye connection the secondary line voltages leads the primary voltages.

However, as stated below it's the opposite. Am I right? I tried understanding the wording but I think I am not getting it accurately.

[image]

SOURCE:

Power System Analysis

John J. Grainger and William D. Stevenson

McGraw-Hill Series in Electrical and Computer Engineering

1994

ISBN 0-07-113338-0